# Adding Google Play Login To Surface View

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, surfaceview

I've read documentation and any guides only explain, how to set it up on an activity. I've tried including:

```
apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(Games.API)
        .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
        .enableAutoManage(this, new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not connect to Play games services");
        finish();
    }
}).build();
```

(example code)

Into my `oncreate` method in my main activity, But as the `main activity` is nothing more than just the loading platform for my surfaceview it doesn't work:

**Main Activity code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // fullscreen
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        // Set No Title

        this.setContentView(new GameSurface(this));
    }

 }
```

I've tried putting it into my `gamesurface` class context but I cant use `getString` to post the scores to the high scores I've made in my developer console.

Has anyone managed to do this doing it with just surfaceview? I thought about having an method to open another class and have that do the login, but how would I push the scores to leader board?

How do I go about even viewing the leader board? `startActivityForResult` doesn't work.

**BASICALLY**
What I want to achieve is have the login automatically happen when game is opened. Then an alternative to `getString` and open the leader boards. Any suggestions would be appreciated. I've been on this for a while.

Comment: Is there a different way to get string in surfaceview?

Comment: Didn't get it, what is your issue exactly? Your SurfaceView is just a layout, `onCreate` is still call so why can't you log the user as explained in the documentation?

Comment: 'onCreate' isn't in my surface view, my service view is separate activity. I've tried to put it In my main activity but I never get a login prompt.

Comment: And how do you submit scores to leaderboards from surface view? It never recognises ' getstring'

Comment: @Eselfar, okay I've fixed the Google login, I changed the main activity to extend fragment, and build api as a public googleapi and now I have the login. Now I need to figure out how to add the scores to the leaderboard. Could I make the voids in the MainActivity and call them from surface view?

Comment: I think you're mixing things. A SurfaceView is just... a View. Means it's just an UI component. The Activity is the base of an Android app. It's in charge of diplaying the UI which can be managed by a Fragment which is a subcomponent able to manage an UI too. Your SurfaceView should only manage what is displayed. You can have a `Game` class to handle the game logic, keep the game object in memory, ... but you'll still have the Activity otherwise your app is just a service and can't have an UI. What is the 'service view' you're talking about? Can you please add a bit of code to your question?

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise I put service view. That's just surface view only miss spelt. Thanks for explication. That's helpful, I'm learning alot still from this game. I'm Frontend  Web developer so I'm still learning java but quite enjoying it. My service view only manages displays, my player logic and enemy logic is all in different classes. But now what I'm struggling to work out is how I can submit the score to my leaderboard? So when the game over happens, my surface view pops up a simple game over drawtext, can I put a void in my main activity, then call that when game ends?

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise I put service view. That's just surface view only miss spelt. Thanks for explication. That's helpful, I'm learning alot still from this game. I'm Frontend  Web developer so I'm still learning java but quite enjoying it. My service view only manages displays, my player logic and enemy logic is all in different classes. But now what I'm struggling to work out is how I can submit the score to my leaderboard? So when the game over happens, my surface view pops up a simple game over drawtext, can I put a void in my main activity, then call that when game ends?

Comment: You like your SurfaceView ;) . Leave it alone. If you know this is the end of the game, it means you component (your Game class probably) managing the game knows this is the end. So it can either send the info to the leaderboard by itself if it has all the necessary info, or preferably it will call a specific method on the Activity with the score to send, and the Activity will be in charge to send the info to the leaderboard.

Comment: I do like the surface view :). The game over happens when the player and enemy touch. Which is handled in my surface  view. It gets the bounds from my two classes and checks if they're touching. I think I might have to go and start again. I think I've not done things correctly. My menu is in my surfaceview as well so I can't get it to show leaderboard, how it would in the documentation. I think I might start again.

Comment: Yes it seems you need to rethink your architecture. It's generally not a good idea to have a big class managing everything. Plus, it's better to separate the view (what is displayed) from the logic (how the thing works). In your case you could have a game class managing the logic and your beloved SurfaceView managing what is displayed and the user interactions. Idk what your game is but let say you have to click to move your player, the SurfaceView will get the touch info and tell the Game that it has been touched in the coordinates x,y.

Comment: Then the Game will manage that (move the user to this point) and tell the SurfaceView to display the player at this new position. When done, the Game can ask the SurfaceView if the player is now touching an enemy (let say the SurfaceView has a player to display and a list of ennemies). The SurfaceView will return true or false and, based on that, the Game will do the appropriate action (e.g. decrease the player's lifes) and call the SurfaceView to display the new state to the user.

Comment: By separating the logic and the view, the Game class doesn't know anything about the UI and it's flexible. The UI could be in 2D and then you want to update if for 3D, the logic will remain, only the view part will change. For example to detect if the player touches an enemy, it's gonna be a different calculation for the view but the game will still call the same method and still get true or false.

Comment: Well thanks for your help. I really dont know what I'm going to do know, The surfaceView only has whats displayed and the user interactions, that bits fine. But i dont really have anything to tell anyone the games over, the surfaceview shows the gameover page and when i tap the screen it resets the view and gameloop. 
Thank you.

Comment: If you don't want to change anything, make the SurfaceView to call the Activity to send the score. If you display it, it means you already have it somewhere, I reckon in your SurfaceView, so the SV just need to call a `gameover`, or whatever you want to call it, method on the Activity with the score as a parameter. And the Activity sends it to the leaderboard

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166826/discussion-between-scott-chambers-and-eselfar).